# Cross-cultural translation of subtext?

Tags: british-english

I am trying to translate an idiomatic Swedish phrase to British English. The problem is that the phrase's meaning is delivered by subtext.

The Swedish phrase is: 'att vara som folk'. Translated verbatim: 'to be like people'.

Put in a context, a Swedish parent might use the phrase to admonish an unruly kid, by, for instance, saying (in translation) something like: 'I won't take you to the fairground until you learn to be like people'.

A Swedish kid would understand the admonishing part of the sentence in the following way: people = normal people = normal behaviour/blending in = my parent think that I am being unruly and is therefore annoyed = my parent demand that I behave properly.

However, would a British kid understand the same demand in the same way? Or, would it rather cause a baffled reaction ('how could I not be like people?? I've been 'people' since I was born!')?

Assuming that I cannot communicate the Swedish meaning via a verbatim translation to BE - would it suffice to let an adjective precede the word "people"? Would demands like 'learn to be like common people/normal people/ordinary folk', etcetera, be understood by a Brit as carrying the subtext 'learn to behave properly'?

You may wonder: why can I not translate it to 'learn to behave normally'?

It is because the phrase is part of a piece of fiction and the translation has quite strict parameters: short phrase (preferably not more than two words after "learn to be"); colloquial language; not on the nose; the last word has to be "people", "folk", or something equivalent.

So, how could I translate it to BE?

(caveat: as it is fiction - with characters acting over the top - whether the language in question would amount to unrealistically improper behaviour by a BE speaker -  the harsh reactions it could cause - is irrelevant. The only concern here is the literal language, which has to at least work so-so; it should not appear as highly unrealistic in the eyes of a Brit).

Comment: Yes. "Why can't you behave like normal people?"

Comment: ' ... until you learn to behave in a civilised manner' [formal].

Comment: Is this a Swedish character? I note you got [quite a drubbing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/246595/british-english-phrase-for-encouraging-normal-behaviour/246596#246596) the last time you asked about this, yesterday, on ELL.

Comment: The meaning must be to *behave like a human being*. Yiddish similarly uses *mensch* from the German (man, human) to mean a decent person: "I'm not being fussy. Just introduce me to a mensch!"

Comment: Michael Harvey@: I am not aware of anything amounting to a "drubbing." Moreover, I think that appearing in this thread with such a claim is both irrelevant and suggests dubious intents. Please quit it.

Comment: *You need to grow up* is possible. Or *you need to act like an adult*. Or even just the admonition *Behave!* But there are several variations of this. Also, if you need an expression that's specifically British, I have no idea what that would be. (None of the suggestions so far are only British.)

Comment: Nitpick warning! I thought "Att vara som folk" meant something along the lines of "He/she puts his/her pants on one leg at a time, just like the rest of us/just like any ordinary person". "Att bete sig som folk" on the other hand, would be fitting for an unruly or disobedient kid.